# Function in an Interface which returns an object of the type of whatever class implements it

Tags: c#, function, inheritance, interface

This is probably best described with an example.

I have two structs: Dog and Cat, which both belong to IAnimal.

IAnimal has a function ConvertFrom(IAnimal) which converts any object that inherits from IAnimal into the same type as called the function.

E.g.:

I call Dog.ConvertFrom(cat) and I get a dog with the fields mapped over from cat.

I call Cat.ConvertFrom(dog) and I get a cat with the fields mapped over from dog.

Is there any way to do this with interfaces? Specify that the function must return the same type as the class that implements the function?

I thought of simply writing it as:

```
IAnimal ConvertFrom(IAnimal)
```

but I'd rather be able to specify that it's coming back as a dog, or a cat, instead of as IAnimal (and thus mitigating a further cast).

Comment: Just so I'm sure what you're asking. Are you asking if static methods, ie. `Dog.ConvertFrom` can be implemented through interfaces?

Comment: Do the `Dog` and the `Cat` have compatible fields ? If so, are you only ever going to use `Dog` and `Cat` ? When you say `Dog.ConvertFrom(cat)` is `ConvertFrom` a static method or an instance method. If you want to do things elegantly I would first suggest you stop mutating things and take the route of the immutable+functional paradigms...

Comment: They have some compatible fields, but not all of them are compatible. And I plan to be extending IAnimal as time goes on to include others, which will need to be converting. Currently I use various interfaces to show what each animal supports (e.g. ICoat, ISpeed, etc.) and can use those to convert between. For a real-life example of what this is for, it's for Direct3D vertex types, they are specified by the shader but typically objects are stored as one type of vertices, and so these conversions need to exist, and need to be extensible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be talking about something like the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to achieve static polymorphism.
You could use generics to have:

```
public interface IAnimal

public interface IAnimal<T> : IAnimal where T : IAnimal<T>

public class Dog : IAnimal<Dog>

public class Cat : IAnimal<Cat>
```

Then your method becomes something like:

```
T ConvertFrom(IAnimal someAnimal)
```